# Unable to read text property using Twitter and Node

Tags: javascript, twitter

In my attempt to do a deep dive with javascript and node, I'm trying to build a small twitter application to collect the last 10 tweets with a given hashtag - the issue arises after the 9 tweet is collected and logged to the console. Depending on the hash tag (I tried #happy earlier in the day, and the program ran without issue), the program either runs as expected or throws and error thinking that the text property is undefined. My code is below:

```
var twit = require('twit')
var config = require('./config.js')


var twitter = new twit(config);

twitter.get('search/tweets', { q: '#happy', count: 9 }, function(err, tweets) {

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (tweets.statuses[i].text) {
      var tweet = tweets.statuses[i].text
      console.log(i)
      console.log(tweet);
    }
  }
});
```

The error I'm receiving after the 9th tweet is displayed in the console is as follows:

```
/Users/seanwelch/Desktop/statusboard/app.js:10
    if (tweets.statuses[i].text) {
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
```

Comment: Your call to twitter passes a "count: 9" which appears to retrieve just the last 9 tweets.  That's why your loop is referencing a null value when it gets to the 10th iteration of your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access a property that doesn't exist, it's possible there aren't 10 tweets with that #hashtag?

I would suggest rewriting your for loop to something along these lines

```
for (var i = 0; i < tweets.statuses.length; i++) {
    var tweet = tweets.statuses[i].text
    console.log(i)
    console.log(tweet);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks the twitter search API was only generating results from a certain timeframe. Your solution totally worked - thank you so much!

Comment: @seanpwelch90 Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it worked! :)